# change the bounds of CGBitmapContext?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

Following is the usual way to create a CGBitmapContext and at its creation we set the context bounds.

```
CGContextRef contextbitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height,8, 
4 * width,
devicecolorspace,                  
kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

I am looking for way to update the bounds of context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Create a new bitmap context. You can transfer the old one's contents to the new one by creating an image from it (`CGBitmapContextCreateImage`) and then drawing that image into the new context.

Comment: I believe there should be a way. Its because, when you resize the window, context bounds get changed and context is still the same. Thoughts?

Comment: There is all sorts of functionality that's available internally in the system that isn't exposed as public API. The management of window backing stores is definitely private.

Comment: I understand that and I can use private stuff. In fact I am using it. But I am unable to find anything related to context resizing.

Comment: What are you doing with this bitmap that has it being resized repeatedly?  Are you using it to cache the graphics being drawn to NSView?

Comment: Yes its kind of caching view. Not exactly view but concept is same.

Answer (score 1):

A Core Graphics context doesn't have “bounds”.  It has a coordinate system, with essentially infinite extent.  You can, for example, do `CGContextFillRect(gc, CGRectInfinite)`.

A bitmap context has an underlying bitmap, and each pixel in the bitmap is mapped to a well-defined region in the context's coordinate system.  (The region is always a parallelogram.)

The initial mapping, when you create a bitmap context, maps the pixels (collectively) to the rectangle `CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)`.

If you want to change this mapping, change the context's *current transform matrix* (CTM).  For example, if you want to map the pixels to the rectangle `CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100, 100)`, do this:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(gc, width / 100.0f, height / 100.0f);
CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, -50, -50);
```